# How to identify elements that belong to a set in a numpy array in python

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a numpy array

```
A = numpy.array([-1, 1, 2, -2, 3, -3])
```

I would like to get all numbers whose squares equal 1 or 9 (so the expected result is `[1, -1, 3, -3]`). I tried `A[A**2 in [1, 9]]` but got an error. Is there any built-in function to handle this simple task without doing loops? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`numpy` has a fucnction that does what you what called `in1d`:

```
import numpy

A = numpy.array([-1, 1, 2, -2, 3, -3])
mask = numpy.in1d(A**2, [1, 9])
print(mask)
# [ True  True False False  True  True]
print(A[mask])
# [-1  1  3 -3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.logical_or` :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A[np.logical_or(A**2==1,A**2==9)]
array([-1,  1,  3, -3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x ** 2 in [1, 9], A)
[-1, 1, 3, -3]
```